# Error al ejecutar en la terminal de vscode

Tags: nodejs, terminal

Este es el error que tengo en la terminal:

> PS C:\Users\JUAN\Desktop\proyectos\java_script> node ./practica.js
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module
> 'C:\Users\JUAN\Desktop\proyectos\java_script\practica.js'
> at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

Coloco imagen por si ayuda más:

[image: es como tengo ubicado todo]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La terminal se encuentra en la carpeta `java_script`.

El archivo que quieres ejecutar se encuentra en la carpeta `clase4`, que está en la carpeta `pages`.

Debería bastar con moverte hasta la carpeta correspondiente:

```sh
cd pages\clase4
node practica.js
```

O escribir bien la ruta relativa o absoluta:

```sh
node pages\clase4\practica.js
```

Recuerda utilizar el separador correspondiente en tu terminal (<kbd>/</kbd> o <kbd>\</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

Creo que faltó importar esto.

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

Previamente debiste instalar console-browserify. Espero haberte ayudado.